How to to monitoring for postgres sql of a windows server using zabbix agent
How I can monitor the Postgres SQL of a Windows server using the Zabbix agent?
I installed Zabbix Agent 2 on Windows. But there is no plug-in for Postgres in Zabbix agent 2 folders.
Please suggest to me how to proceed further.

check the ODBC template: https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/postgresql_odbc
